# genfromtxt load data arranged in lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data csv files with the following format:

```
130, 706, 249, 627, 428, 767, 430,  63, 884, 593
964, 340, 848, 607, 142, 517, 294, 453, 398, 236, 314, 653, 211, 439, 226
```

Is there a way to load this data so that the final array contains the transposed version of the data in the file and the end of the shortest column (i.e. the shortest line in the data file) contains nan values?

the final result should be as following:

```
array([[130, 964],
[706, 340],
[249, 848],
[627, 607],
[428, 142],
[767, 517],
[430, 294],
[63, 453],
[884, 398],
[593, 236],
[np.nan, 314], 
[np.nan, 653],
[np.nan, 211],
[np.nan, 439],
[np.nan, 226]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

gen = (line.strip().split(',') for line in open('test.txt'))
np.float_(list(izip_longest(*gen, fillvalue=np.nan)))
```

which gives:

```
array([[ 130.,  964.],
       [ 706.,  340.],
       [ 249.,  848.],
       [ 627.,  607.],
       [ 428.,  142.],
       [ 767.,  517.],
       [ 430.,  294.],
       [  63.,  453.],
       [ 884.,  398.],
       [ 593.,  236.],
       [  nan,  314.],
       [  nan,  653.],
       [  nan,  211.],
       [  nan,  439.],
       [  nan,  226.]])
```

Comment: yes it works quite nicely but I was thinking of numpy.genfromtxt for its features.

Comment: @user1850133 I see, but unfortunately `genfromtxt` cannot deal with this kind of missing values. You could probably do `np.genfromtxt(izip_longest(*gen, fillvalue=np.nan))` and get the same result, plus some other resources of `genfromtxt()` that you might need...

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if your file had empty fields separated by commas, like this:

```
130, 706, 249, 627, 428, 767, 430,  63, 884, 593,    ,    ,    ,    ,
964, 340, 848, 607, 142, 517, 294, 453, 398, 236, 314, 653, 211, 439, 226
```

Then you'd be able to just do:

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('csv.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
array([[ 130.,  964.],
       [ 706.,  340.],
       [ 249.,  848.],
       [ 627.,  607.],
       [ 428.,  142.],
       [ 767.,  517.],
       [ 430.,  294.],
       [  63.,  453.],
       [ 884.,  398.],
       [ 593.,  236.],
       [  nan,  314.],
       [  nan,  653.],
       [  nan,  211.],
       [  nan,  439.],
       [  nan,  226.]])
```

Note that this is a float array. It seems like you can't have `nan`s in an integer array. You can use a masked array though:

```
np.ma.masked_equal(
      np.genfromtxt('csv.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=int, unpack=True),
      -1)
```

So it may be easier to just pre-process your file (if you know the number of columns):

```
with open('csv.csv') as fin, open('new.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace('\n', ',' * (14 - line.count(',')) + '\n'))
```

where `14` is the number of columns minus 1.